Reference request: Closed form of elementary symmetric polynomials of principal curvatures of implicit defined surface
Let $f\colon R^d \to R$ be smooth. By $H_j(x_1,...,x_k)$, we denote the $j$-th elementary symmetric function, and by $κ_1, . . . , κ_{d−1}$ we denote the principal curvatures of $f^{-1}(u)$. Then
$$  H_{d−1−k}(κ_1,...,κ_{d−1}) = \lVert ∇f\rVert ^{-(d-1-k)}detr_{d−1−k}(M(∇f)D^2fM(∇f)), $$
where $M(x):= I_d - \lVert x\rVert^{-2} xx^T$ and $detr_k$ is the $k$-th subdeterminant.
The formula follows from

the outer unit normal vector of $f^{-1}(u)$ is given by $∇f/\lVert ∇f\rVert$
the shape operator is given by $1/\lVert ∇f\rVert ( M(∇f)D^2fM(∇f)$

Could you please recommend a reference or section in a book or paper that provides the explicit expression?
